# How do I fix this so that I don't get an attribute error when executing main()?

Tags: python

Trying to do some test runs and running into a wall with my code. I'm receiving this error: "Exception has occurred: AttributeError
'str' object has no attribute '_price'"
when I run main() and provide my sample ticker aapl.

I've tried changing the return value to self._price, get_live_value(ticker) and passing ticker into the parameters.

```
"""
This will import yahoo finance api to grab information and sort through 50
different stocks
"""
from yahoo_fin.stock_info import \*

class stocks():
"""
Class stocks performs functions from the yahoo_fin package
"""

    # Annotate variables
    _ticker: str
    _price: float
    
    def __init__(self, ticker: str) -> None:
        """
        Initializes the parameters
        """
        self._ticker = ticker
        self._price = get_live_price(ticker)
    
    def __str__(self) -> str:
        """
        Returns a string version of the object
        """
        return f"{self._ticker}, {self._price}"
    
    def get_ticker(self) -> str:
        """
        Returns the ticker
        """
        return self._ticker
    def get_price(self) -> float:
        """
        Returns the price
        """
        return self._price

"""
Testing the import openpyxl module
"""

    # Imports from openpyxl and openpyxl.utils
    
    from openpyxl import Workbook, load_workbook
    from openpyxl.utils import get_column_letter
    from stocks import stocks
    def main():
    \# Accessing excel sheet using load_workbook
    wb = load_workbook('Stocks.xlsx')
    ws = wb.active
    
        # Asks the user to enter a ticker of a company
        ticker = input("Please enter a ticker for a company: ")
        user = stocks(ticker)
        
        price = stocks.get_price(ticker)
        
        
        # Adds titles to columns
        ws['A' + str(1)] = "Ticker"
        ws['B' + str(1)] = "Live Price"
        
        # Modifies the cells to display information and tidy up the appearance
        for row in range(2, 3):
            ws['A' + str(row)] = str(user.get_ticker().upper())
            ws['B' + str(row)] = float("{:.2f}".format(price))
        
        # Saves the document at the end of the code to update the actual excel sheet
        wb.save('Stocks.xlsx')
    
    main()
```

Comment: `stocks` is the name of the class. If you do `price = stocks.get_price(ticker)`, you're not calling that method on an instance of that class, but on the class itself, which means the first parameter `self` will come from whatever argument you pass in, in this case `ticker`. You want to do `price = user.get_price()` instead, though it's not really clear why that line is there to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like it's an issue with the calling of the function get_price rather than the definition. It looks like you initialize the user variable and use it later in the line

```
ws['A' + str(row)] = str(user.get_ticker().upper())
```

but you don't use it with the get_price function. It seems like the line

```
price = stocks.get_price(ticker)
```

should be

```
price = user.get_price()
```

Although it is not entirely necessary, it might make sense to keep the format the same. It might be easier to look at if you put the `get_price` function in line when adding it to the table like you did for the `get_ticker` function like so:

```
ws['B' + str(row)] = float("{:.2f}".format(user.get_price()))
```

and remove the price variable all together.

In the future, you may want to refrain from defining the self variable when calling the function. 
**Do**

```
object.function()
```

**Do not**

```
class.function(object)
```